# Display list of countries in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, listview, listbox, windows-phone-8.1, longlistselector

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 App  (WINRT)**

I want to display a **list of countries** in registration page out of which user can select one. In Windows Phone 7, we used to have **LongListSelector**.

What is its replacement in Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT).

Actually, I want users to click on this control and it should open in **fullscreenmode**.

I am confused between ListView, ListBox, Semanticzoom

I am currently using:

```
<ListView
                                              Name="UserCountry_ListPicker"
                                            FullModeHeader="Select Country:"
                                    SelectedIndex="-1" 
                                    Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_DarkBlueColor}"
                                    FontWeight="ExtraLight"  
                                    Margin="0,5,0,0"
                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_DarkBlueColor}"
                                    BorderThickness="0.2,0.2,0.2,3"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Background="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_TextBoxBackground_Light}" 
                                            SelectionChanged="UserCountry_ListPicker_SelectionChanged">
                                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel 
                                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                                        <Border 
                                                    Background="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_DarkBlueColor}"
                                                    Width="28" 
                                                    Height="28">
                                                            <TextBlock 
                                                        Text="{Binding CountryWithCodesGroupItem_Symbol}" 
                                                        FontSize="14" 
                                                        FontWeight="ExtraLight"
                                                        Foreground="WhiteSmoke"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                        </Border>
                                                        <TextBlock 
                                                    Text="{Binding CountryWithCodesGroupItem_Name}" 
                                                    FontWeight="ExtraLight"
                                                    Margin="12 0 0 0"
                                                    FontSize="21"/>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <ListView.FullModeItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel 
                                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                Margin="20,5,0,5"
                                                  >
                                                        <Border 
                                                    Background="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_DarkBlueColor}"
                                                    Width="68" 
                                                    Height="68">
                                                            <TextBlock 
                                                        Text="{Binding CountryWithCodesGroupItem_Symbol}" 
                                                        FontSize="26" 
                                                        FontWeight="ExtraLight"
                                                        Foreground="WhiteSmoke"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                        </Border>
                                                        <TextBlock 
                                                    Text="{Binding CountryWithCodesGroupItem_Name}" 
                                                    FontWeight="ExtraLight"
                                                            Name="CountryNames"
                                                    Margin="12 0 0 0"
                                                            Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_DarkBlueColor}"
                                                    FontSize="26" 
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListView.FullModeItemTemplate>

                                            <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                Margin="0,0,0,-5">
                                                        <TextBlock
                                                    Name="UserCountry_Label" 
                                                     FontSize="25"
                                                   FontWeight="ExtraLight"
                                                    Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_DarkBlueColor}"
                                                    Text="Country">
                                                        </TextBlock>
                                                        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Images/Login_RegistrationPage/athteriskRedForm_01.png"
                                                        Margin="3,0,0,0">
                                                        </Image>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                                        </ListView>
```

But it shows opened list on page. Can't I have it closed on page like this:
[example image](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSbVgXehtI1YS0Y8GQZ2lP5xUtc1HVrLv59v54qTICJshAhhqNl6g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you will consider using [ListPickerFlyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listpickerflyout.aspx):

```xml
<Button Content="Choose country">
   <Button.Flyout>
      <ListPickerFlyout ItemsSource="{Binding CountryList}" Placement="Full" ItemsPicked="Items_PickedEven">
         <ListPickerFlyout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountryName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ListPickerFlyout.ItemTemplate>
      </ListPickerFlyout>
   </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

You may also think of [using general Flyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308515.aspx) and define it's content as ListView, ListBox or other.

Comment: @AtifShabeer Take a look at documentation and give it a try - you have some helpful properties *SelectedItem(s)*, also once you pick an item then *ItemsPicked* event is fired, you probably can also do something in closed event.

Comment: I USED ListView instead of above code. It displays list of countries in page and makes my registration page to scroll. Can't I have this ListView in minimised/closed mode on page?

Comment: @AtifShabeer You can use general flyout and put your ListView there - you will have a button and upon click your listview will appear. Take a look at the link in last sentence of the answer.

Comment: https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSbVgXehtI1YS0Y8GQZ2lP5xUtc1HVrLv59v54qTICJshAhhqNl6g

Comment: Can you please have a look at above url, i want it to be like the example above.

Comment: @AtifShabeer I'm confused if youe are looking for *ComboBox* or fullscreen list from which you can pick up an element.

Comment: In the link "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSbVgXehtI1YS0Y8GQZ2lP5xUtc1HVrLv59v54qTICJshAhhqNl6g" there is an option to select USE ADDRESS BAR BUTTON FOR. Accurately same thing i want to implement. But problem is my control is shown as WEBSITE PREFERNCE , i mean the list is pre-opened on page. I want list to be closed like in case of USE ADDRESS BAR BUTTON FOR

Answer (score 0):

As far as the differences between the three are concerned, `ListView` is essentially like a `ListBox` however it also has a `View` property that `ListBox` does not have. The `View` property is useful for specifying a prefdefined way to display items.

A `SemanticZoom` control often has a `ListView` control within it, and allows you to switch between two different views of the list's data set.